# Delete UITableVIewCell from another view controller file in Xcode

Tags: swift, xcode, uitableview

I have an array "numbers" which I call in my table view file to make the table view cells. When one is clicked it goes to a view controller which shows details about that cell, and in within that view controller is a delete button. How would I delete the item from the array, and reload the data in the table view controller?

So I set it up that when the delete button is clicked it runs an exit code, and deletes the item from the array, and reloads the data. I tried testing it but it never seems to execute.

This is in the detailViewController where it runs the exit function and runs the protocol to delete the item from the array

```
func deleteNumber() {
    self.delegate?.unwind()
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.5) { // Change `2.0` to the desired number of seconds.
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "unwindToNumbersList2WithSender", sender: self)
    }
}
```

Then in the table view controller it runs this:

```
func unwind() {
        numbers.remove(at: indexPath.row)
        tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)
        saveNumbers()
}
```

I also tried using:

```
func unwind() {
        numbers.remove(at: indexPath.row)
        tableView.reloadData()
        saveNumbers()
}
```

So I wanted it to run an either delete the row or delete the item from the array, and reload the data, but neither of those ran. Is there a way I can delete it from the detail view controlle?

Comment: Use notification center

Comment: @SPatel what do you mean by that?

Comment: Your code looks fine to me. Are you sure `indexPath.row` has the right value? Are you sure `saveNumbers` does not restore the datasource?

Comment: @VinodVishwanath let me check that. I’m thinking I may have a problem with the protocol cause I don’t think that’s running either

Answer (score 0):

You can use `NotificationCenter` for doing this,

First you need to add notification in `UIViewController` like this

```
let DELETE_DATA = "DELETE_DATA".notificationName()

NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.delete_data), name: DELETE_DATA, object: nil)
```

Make a function named `delete_data`

```
 @objc func delete_data(_ notification : NSNotification){
    let userData = notification.userInfo as? [String:Any] ?? [String:Any]()

    // here you can get your wanted index to be deleted.
}
```

From details view controller you need to POST this notification with index you want to delete

```
let obj = ["index":`your index to be deleted`]

NotificationCenter.default.post(name: DELETE_DATA, object: nil, userInfo: obj)
```

Comment: For the first part should I declare that in viewDidLoad() of the detail view controller then add the function in the table view controller

Comment: You need to do addObserver at place where you need to delete item from array in viewDidLoad() and let DELETE_DATA = "DELETE_DATA".notificationName() this you can define global so you can use it in another controller when you post notification

Comment: This is a bad answer. The notification center is just one of many ways to broadcast messages for the detail-view-controller to communicate with its delegate. The OP has already established a perfectly reasonable way for this communication and using the NotificationCenter is an unnecessary tangent.

Comment: Well, I still tried it but I kept getting the error Extra argument 'object' in call. What does that mean?